# How can I make a function to check if a parameter is a number and have it accept an undefined parameter?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
    isNumber: function (num) {
        // Return false if num is null or an empty string
        if (num === null || (typeof num === "string" && num.length === 0)) {
            return false;
        }
        var rtn = !isNaN(num)
        return rtn;

    },
```

This gives me a problem if num is not yet defined. How can I make it return false when num is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You could use "loose" comparison when you compare against `null`:

```
num == null
```

This will be `true` if `num` is `undefined` or `null` (and only then).

You can also simplify the string comparison so that the overall test is:

```
num == null || num === ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (num === null || (typeof num === "string" && num.length === 0))
```

with

```
if (num === null || typeof num === "undefined" || (typeof num === "string" && num.length === 0))
```

as you see, the new condition also handles the case in which `num` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if no value was passed to the function by testing the array of the `arguments` passed to the function; so if `arguments.length=0` then no arguments were passed to the function and `num` will not be defined.

You could also do further checks against `num !== undefined && num !== null` (note that non-identity operator `!==` is used instead of non-equality operator `!=`).

Instead you could just check that if you parse the number it is a valid non-infinite number:

```
isNumber: function (num) {
    if ( arguments.length == 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(num))&&isFinite(num);
}
```

This checks if:

- `parseFloat(num)` evaluates to a valid number; and if
- `isFinite(num)` - that valid number is not positive or negative infinity.

If this meets your criteria then you don't need the first check (since `parseFloat(undefined)` returns `NaN`) and can simplify the function to:

```
isNumber: function (num) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(num))&&isFinite(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric).

```
<script>
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

alert(isNumber());            //false
alert(isNumber(10));          //true
alert(isNumber(null));        //false
alert(isNumber(undefined));   //false
</script>
```